# `/bin/bash: -c: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file` obscure error when changing variable in a Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, autotools, automake

I've got this strange thing happening which seems totally unrelated to the error I got afterwards.

My AutoTools build system works great, but if I change [this line](https://github.com/GNOME/banshee/blob/master/build/build.dist.mk#L2) in my Makefile, to use `$(top_builddir)` instead of `$(top_srcdir)`, then the build starts failing this way:

```
...
/usr/bin/mcs -r:/usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../lib/cli/glib-sharp-3.0/glib-sharp.dll -out:gobject-intptr-ctor-verifier.exe GObjectIntPtrCtorVerifier.cs
Making all in Hyena
/bin/bash: -c: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

How the hell this single change can cause this and how to debug this problem? How to know what file is bash trying to interpret? I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Could this be a UNIX/Windows line endings issue?

Comment: nope, I'm in Linux all the time

Comment: and, if it was, what file should I look at? it's not clear at all from the error message

Comment: I'm not sure - I haven't looked at the file you've linked to. It would be useful if you could reduce your Makefile to a minimal reproducible test case and include it here.

Comment: it would take very long to reduce to a minimal testcase, and I would find the problem when I do it, I was mainly asking in stackoverflow to see if it rings a bell to someone or to maybe realize about a shortcut way to debug it, how to instruct /bin/bash to tell me the file it's looking into??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try tracing the commands that are executed.  Maybe `make` can be modified to be more verbose.  Otherwise I suggest `strace`:

```
original_command='make all' # or whatever it was you executed

strace -s2000 -eexecve -o/tmp/make.commands -f $original_command
```

Then look at the file `/tmp/make.commands`, search for bash, and in particular search for inline shell scripts that are 13 lines long.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you solved your problem. In the more general case, this error, and other similar errors, are usually caused by a syntax error in the Automake file that makes its way into the Makefile. Sometimes a line number in the Makefile is reported, so you can examine the generated Makefile; in your case it wasn't.

`make -n` can help, by printing out each command that `make` would execute without actually executing it.